# Different quotient, what does 'a' represent?

Tags: calculus

My book says :

Different quotient represents the average rate of change of $f(x)$ between x = $a$ and $x = a + h$

the question ask for $f(a)$:

$f(x) = x^3$ therefore,

$f(a) =$

I have tried $f(a) = x^3$ and $f(a) = f(x)$ and this answers are incorrect. what confuses me is that if the definition says $x = a$ then why is $f(a) = f(x)$ not true.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking too hard. If $f(x)=x^3$, then $f(a)=a^3$. The expression $f(a)$ means the value of the function $f$ evaluated at $x=a$.

To see more examples,
$$
f(1)=1^3,\quad f(2)=2^3,\quad f(\pi)=\pi^3,\cdots
$$

Comment: nice , your explanation was very clear.